# Get Kendo Grid form data string

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I am creating a report using grid data, and so that I can steal the exact same appearance I am trying to call kendo grids handler in MVC from my own method.

I observed that kendo sends this when updating the grid:

```
sort:dueDate-desc
page:1
pageSize:20
group:
filter:
```

To format this so far I've just looped through and manually created the form data, eg for the sort field:

```
     var sortSet = grid.dataSource.sort();
     var sortString = '&sort=';
     for (var i = 0; i < sortSet.length; i++) {
        sortString = sortString + sortSet[i].field + '-' + sortSet[i].dir + '~';
     }
```

Is there a way to get kendo to do this? A place where its storing the string already?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, missed something! What is what you are trying to do, save current _status_ of the grid for _replaying_ it in the future (when report is recovered). Is this correct? Basically you just need: page size (if it is not always the same), page number, sorting and filtering criteria. You can do all of this programmatically. Is this correct?

Comment: Kendo sends the page, pagesize, group and filter to the controller when remote data is requested. I am trying to get this URL, so that when I call to create a report (using a different controller), the controller can call the kendo datasource on the server with the details already loaded. Thats basically what my code is accomplishing now, I'm just curious if the URL form data already exists in a serialised form in kendo for me to use without my own handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the approach to generate the link from the code libraries which refer to exporting the Grid data. Here is one for [PDF](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/export-grid-to-pdf.aspx).

Basically the magic code which updates the URL of the link using the **dataBound** event is as follows:

```
//initial URL of the link is generated with this helper

Url.Action("Export", "Home", new { page = 1, pageSize = "~", filter = "~", sort = "~" })


<script type="text/javascript">
    function onDataBound(e) {
        var grid = $('#Grid').data('kendoGrid');

        // ask the parameterMap to create the request object for you
        var requestObject = (new kendo.data.transports["aspnetmvc-server"]({ prefix: "" }))
        .options.parameterMap({
            page: grid.dataSource.page(),
            sort: grid.dataSource.sort(),
            filter: grid.dataSource.filter()
        });

        // Get the export link as jQuery object
        var $exportLink = $('#export');

        // Get its 'href' attribute - the URL where it would navigate to
        var href = $exportLink.attr('href');

        // Update the 'page' parameter with the grid's current page
        href = href.replace(/page=([^&]*)/, 'page=' + requestObject.page || '~');

        // Update the 'sort' parameter with the grid's current sort descriptor
        href = href.replace(/sort=([^&]*)/, 'sort=' + requestObject.sort || '~');

        // Update the 'pageSize' parameter with the grid's current pageSize
        href = href.replace(/pageSize=([^&]*)/, 'pageSize=' + grid.dataSource._pageSize);

        //update filter descriptor with the filters applied

        href = href.replace(/filter=([^&]*)/, 'filter=' + (requestObject.filter || '~'));

        // Update the 'href' attribute
        $exportLink.attr('href', href);
    }
</script>
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you define in your `dataSource` the options `serverAggregates`, `serverFiltering`, `serverGrouping`, `serverPaging` and / or `serverSorting`, KendoUI will send those parameters to the server for letting it what needs to be done and the different parameters needed for it.

In those cases, you might define `transport.parameterMap` or `transport.read.data` that allows you *translate* or add parameters from KendoUI internal format to your server format, so you can intercept here the request and saving the parameter list of the last request for using it latter.

**Option1**:

```
var savedParamAsJSON = undefined;
var savedParamAsStringifiedJSON = undefined;
var savedParamAsUriEncoded = undefined;
var savedParamAsUriDecoded = undefined;

var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    serverPaging   : true,
    serverSorting  : true,
    serverFiltering: true,
    transport      : {
        read        : {
            url : "data.json"
        },
        parameterMap: function (data, type) {
            if (type === "read") {
                savedParamAsJSON = data;
                savedParamAsStringifiedJSON = JSON.stringify(data);
                savedParamAsUriEncoded = encodeURIComponent(jQuery.param(data));
                savedParamAsUriDecoded = jQuery.param(data);

                // Actual update the link
                $("#exportLink").attr("href", "http://www.onabai.com?" + savedParamAsUriDecoded);
            }
        }
    },
    schema         : {
        model: {
            id    : "ID",
            fields: {
                ID: { type: "number"}
            }
        }
    },
    pageSize       : 8

});
```

In `parameterMap` I save it in four different formats:

1. In `savedParamAsJSON` and `savedParamAsStringifiedJSON` is stored as a JSON object or its *stringified* representation (ex: `{"take":8,"skip":0,"page":1,"pageSize":8}`).
2. In `savedParamAsUriEncoded` is stored as a string but as URI encoded (ex: `take%3D8%26skip%3D0%26page%3D1%26pageSize%3D8`)
3. In `savedParamAsUriDecoded`is stored as a string but not URI encoded (ex: `take=8&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=8`).

**Option2:** You can do it also in `transport.read.data` defining a function for saving the data:

```
transport      : {
    read        : {
        url : "data.json",
        data: function (data) {
            savedParamAsJSON = data;
            savedParamAsStringifiedJSON = JSON.stringify(data);
            savedParamAsUriEncoded = encodeURIComponent(jQuery.param(data));
            savedParamAsUriDecoded = jQuery.param(data);

            // Actual update the link
            $("#exportLink").attr("href", "http://www.onabai.com?" + savedParamAsUriDecoded);
        }
    }
},
```